How much heat do non-IC can lights covered with boxes lose compared to IC-rated can lights with insulation?
Over the long-term, do non-IC recessed lights with insulated Tenmat cover lose more heat than IC-rated lights?
I just bought my first home, and there are several recessed lights in the living area and kitchen. They are non-IC lights (and unfortunately I have to leave them turned off for now, because there is insulation contacting them and the home inspector did not report this). There is an unfinished attic above.
I can either trim the insulation from the lights and install light covers or boxes (for example by Tenmat). Or I could replace the lights altogether with IC-rated and air tight lights. Either way, I'd like to do an LED conversion.
What does anyone think is the best thing to do long-term? I know it's a lot less expensive to put Tenmat light covers on. But over time would they still lose more heat than IC-rated lights covered in insulation?
Thanks in advance. I've read a few posts about recessed lights here but didn't see something exactly like this question.

This is an opinion-based question so likely to be closed.

Good to know. I can clarify so that it's less opinion-based: Over the long-term, do non-IC recessed lights with insulated Tenmat cover lose more heat than IC-rated lights?

For Long term use LED lights

"IC" and "non-IC" apparently are common acronyms in lighting, but not necessarily known to all (like me). A web-search shows it means "Insulation Contact", meaning whether the light is rated to touch insulation or has to be kept away from insulation.

I'd lean towards talking to your insurance company about this. They'd be the ones who'll say "This was no good, you should have swapped the lights" if they don't like the Tenmats et al after a fire.

Some things to consider... • The reason for IC-rated fixtures is the heat from incandescent bulbs. If your home inspector did not suggest changing the bulbs, he/she is not worth your money.  • More important is air sealed fixtures so conditioned air is not escaping into your attic.  • If you want to go LED, the latest 'puck' style lights are pretty much all rated IC. You may be able to find some that will fit the opening for the existing cans, so you could leave those in place.  • Another LED option are the replacement trims with integral LEDs. Either LED type could be air-sealed easily.

Since this is a fact-based forum, Let's review the problem, solutions, and their pros and cons.
*Edit: the question was changed after this answer was submitted. The answer addresses the original question — Which is better to address an inspection issue of non-IC can lights covered with insulation: replace with IC, or add a cover or box over the existing.
The problem — Insulation over non-IC rated recessed light fixtures (can lights). The real problems here, encapsulated within "IC rated" are 1) heat produced by the incandescent bulbs the fixture is rated for, and 2) air sealing. IC-rated fixtures are typically air sealed, non-IC are often not. (Note this is "typical" so may not apply to your can lights.)
Discussion: It sounds, OP, like you are focused on the safety aspects of this problem. You may have a home inspector who has just recently been trained and certified on the thousands of possible dangers and risks present in modern homes, but limited practical experience dealing with them. That is not to downplay those, rather to emphasise that there are some other considerations that have a bigger impact on your home and your life.
One of those is air sealing, or conditioned air escaping into your (not conditioned) attic space along with heat and humidity. Heating and cooling cost money, and humidity can cause other problems in your attic.
Another consideration is that any new fixtures will have built-in high temperature cutoffs. Those exist to further mitigate risk of fire from overheating. Your existing can lights may or may not have them, depending on how old they are, and so may be a factor in your decision.
Solution 1 — Change the recessed fixtures to similar but IC-rated ones.
Pro: You may keep using wasteful incandescent bulbs.
Con: You will keep using wasteful incandescent bulbs.
Pro: Incandescent bulbs will be less likely to cause a fire. In the unlikely event they do, your insurance company will have one less possible reason to deny a claim.
Con: A lot of avoidable effort / money, with limited benefits.
Con: Requires re-wiring, possibly an electrician and a permit.
Con: Requires removing and replacing the insulation. (Maybe not a big deal, but you will get dirty doing it.)
Pro: IC-rated fixtures will be air-sealed, lowering heating/cooling costs and potential for problems cause by excess humidity in your attic.
Pro: You can install fixtures that are different/preferable for other reasons (color, style, features, etc.).
Solution 2 — Cover the non-IC fixtures so the attic insulation no longer contacts them. Pre-fabricated covers are available online, or you can just build a box over each one that will keep the insulation a safe distance away. 'Boxing over' can lights is an older solution, mostly made obsolete by IC-rated fixtures.
Pro: Less money and effort than replacing all of the fixtures.
Pro: Does not require re-wiring.
Pro: Can provide some air sealing, with additional effort & materials.
Con: Still quite a bit of money / effort.
Con: Requires removing and replacing the insulation.
Solution 3 - Just replace the incandescent bulbs with LED bulbs and stop worrying.
Pro: Lowest cost / effort.
Pro: Something you want to do anyways, for other reasons.
Pro: Removes the potential fire risk (due to overheating).
Pro: Does not require any wiring / electrician / permits.
Pro: Removes (mostly) the potential fire risk.
Con: Technically not a solution since it leaves insulation on the non-IC fixtures, so if there is a fire, your insurance could use it to deny a claim.
Con: Does not provide any air sealing.
Solution 4 — Install retrofit trims with integral LEDs into the existing fixtures.
Pro: Less money and effort than replacing fixtures or installing covers. (About the same as new LED bulbs.)
Pro: LEDs you want to do anyways, for other reasons.
Pro: Can be done without attic access or replacing insulation.
Pro: Does not require any re-wiring.
Pro: Removes the potential fire risk, and your insurance company will likely not have an excuse.
Pro: Easily replaced later if your needs/tastes/technology change.
Con: Does not provide any air sealing without additional effort.
Con: Difficult for special situations (e.g. eyeball / gimbal lights).
Now, you could caulk the trims in place or achieve air sealing some other way, but retrofit trims are not designed for it. That also makes them more-or-less permanent.
Solution 5 — Replace the can lights with recessed low-profile LED lights.
Pro: Lower cost than replacement IC-rated fixtures or covers (but more than retrofit LED trims).
Pro: LEDs you want to do anyways, for other reasons.
Pro: Less effort than replacing entire fixtures.
Pro: Can provide good air sealing, with additional effort & materials.
Pro: Can be done without attic access or replacing insulation.
Pro: You can install fixtures that are different/preferable for other reasons (color, style, features, etc.).
Con: Requires re-wiring.
Con: These are replacement fixtures, so you are mostly stuck with them (there are no bulbs to change).
Con: Difficult for special situations (e.g. eyeball / gimbal lights).

Thanks for the detailed response. My main concern is to find out how much heat escapes through non-IC lights that have been covered with boxes, compared to IC-rated can lights covered with insulation.

That's an ordinary heat-loss calculation. Not trivial, but doable. OTOH, it is likely permissible to put insulation over the boxes.
Consider also that replacing can lights is a pita, but very doable. Most existing ones can be completely disassembled from below the ceiling. If you have not found them already, there are can lights designed for retrofit (i.e. install without access above the ceiling.)

An off-the-cuff answer to your ^^ question is "it depends." First, on how you build the boxes, and second, on how well you insulate over them. Seemingly slight air leakage will suck far more heat out of your conditioned space than lack of R-value ever could.

If it were my house, I would get LED retrofit trims and buy or make some foam rings to seal them. No wiring, no crawling in the attic or digging through dirty insulation.
If you really want to know — like, numerically and exactly — ORNL has some great resources for modeling heat and moisture transfer in building structures.
